# output lastwritetime to file if true, and if false, print text on screen

Tags: file, powershell, if-statement

|I've kludged together a little script which, displays on screen the files as they're being processed to let the admin know the script is working, and then outputs the names of any files older modified within the last 6 months to a tx.t or csv:

```
get-childitem z:\directory\ -recurse | %(write-host Processing File: $_.fullname; $_} | Where{$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).addDays(-182) | out-file C:\scriptoutput\
```

This seems to work really well but I'd like to tweak it to come so that 
1. it still mentions that the files are being process.
2. if are no items that are in that directory and subdirectories it doesn't output a file but just prints on the screen that there are no files older than 6 months.

I'd been tryign something along the lines of:

```
$Files= @(get-childitem z:\directory\ -recurse | where{$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).AddDays(182)} | %{write-host processing file: %_.fullname' $_})
If ($Files.lastwritetime -gt (get-date.adddays(-182))} | out-file 'c:\scriptoutput\'
Else ($files.lastwritetime lt (get-date.adddays(-182))} | {write-host "****NO FILES WERE MODIFIED IN THE LAST 6 MONTHS****})
```

Obviously this isn't working, I'm getting a Missing statemnt block after if (condition) error.  Can anyone assist a TOTAL NOOB with where to go with this one?

Much appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple typo issue. The command

```
%{write-host processing file: %_.fullname' $_}
```

contains unbalanced quotes. Try

```
%{write-host "processing file: %_.fullname" $_}
```

In order to catch this kind of errors, use editor like SciTE or the built-in Powershell ISE. The editors have color hints for syntax elements. When an unbalanced quote is encountered, the result looks a mess. Note that a lot of text is cyan instead of blue and black:

[image: Syntax highlighting in action]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this, but i am not quite sure if that is what you were after.

```
$files = @(get-childitem z:\directory\ -recurse | where {$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).AddDays(-182)})
if ($files.Count -gt 0)
{
    $files | % 
    {
        $_.FullName | Out-file  'c:\scriptoutput\somecsv.csv' -Append
    }
}
else
{
    write-host "****NO FILES WERE MODIFIED IN THE LAST 6 MONTHS****"
}
```

Comment: This seems like it might be close to what I want to do although it comes up with a message saying:  cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 1 Supply values for the following parameters: